# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: java, android, signalr, signalr-2

When i use
implementation files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
Then my application not install in my Device
[Here is image where error show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRzzM.jpg)
I try so many solution like

```
1:`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

2:splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
3:-r -t in Flag
```

But not working any other Solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you try as follows:
[image]

disable "Use libusb backend"